# Abrir terminal interativo

Tags: docker

Tenho o seguinte Docker-compose:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  web:
    image: php:7.0-apache
    volumes:
      - ../Desenvolvimento Web/:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Como posso subir estes containers de modo a poder conectar ao terminal deles? Já tentei subir como:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está subindo o container de forma correta. Para abrir um shell neste container, você precisa executar um *docker exec*:

```
docker exec -it seu-container-mysql bash
```

Para desconectar do terminal, tecle:

```
Ctrl+p e Ctrl+q
```

Ou:

`Ctrl+d`

Note que o CTRL+d irá encerrar a sessão aberta, fechando quaisquer jobs que você tenha deixado rodando. A primeira forma apenas desconecta sem matar a sessão.